# Force VMWare Workstation 6.5 to run 32-bit Host

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

I'm on Vista 64-bit, and I need to have VMWare Workstation run as a 32-bit process for reasons outside of the scope of this problem. Right now when I run VMWare, it starts it as a 64-bit process, and I have no idea how to make it run as a 32-bit process instead.

The guest OS is Windows XP (32-bit) if that matters, but I doubt it does.

Comment: can you explain why it matters if the vmware application is 32-bit? Also, since vmware works on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of windows. They likely have both versions in the installer.

Comment: All I know is that it has a x64 folder, and that is what's running the VM, when I don't want the VM to run in a 64-bit host.

Comment: Also, certain parts of vmware will *have* to be 64-bit on a 64-bit OS. Specifically all of the kernel mode drivers it uses. Since this does the vast majority of the virtualization work. I can't see how it would matter to you as long as you can use a 32-bit guest.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure what you want is possible given how vmware is setup. What is it that you can't accomplish with a 64-bit host?

Comment: Control of the VMWare process by tools that were written for 32-bit processes.

Comment: @Daniel: ok, now we are getting somewhere. Are you using the VIX API? Or something else to control it?

Answer (score 2):

OK, since we've discussed in the comments what it is you are **really** trying to do. I will answer the question.

First, your original question: **"How do you run a 32-bit vmware host on 64-bit windows?"**

From looking at the VMware site and documentation, there is no indication that this is possible. If you **really** need to do this, run it on a 32-bit version of windows.

Now on to what you are actually trying to do: You have indicated that you have tools written which are used for controlling the VMware processes. The proper API to do this is the [VIX API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/) or using the vmrun application (the later is more for scripting from a shell). I am assuming VIX. If you are using this. I imagine that ensuring you have the latest copy of the SDK and recompiling your apps should allow them to work with the 64-bit version of VMware.

**EDIT:** going to the VIX SDK download page shows "VIX API for Window 32-bit and 64-bit". This indicates that if you use that version of the SDK, you should be good to go with a 64-bit VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to ask over at the [VMware Forums](http://communities.vmware.com/) where you can get an answer direct from the developers.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem.  I was running VMWare on 64bit Vista but I could only get VMWare to load 32 bit OSs.  It turns out on a Dell you have to go into the BIOS to set up "virtualization" to be either 32 or 64 bit.  Not sure what kind of hardware you are on but check the BIOS to see if you have the same setting.  It doesn't affect the base OS at all, just the virtual ones.

Comment: that is actually the opposite of his problem :). He wants to control whether the *Host* is 32-bit, not the guest. However, your advice is correct for enabling 64-bit guests.